# Possible to delete root partition

Tags: partitioning, format, disk-utility

I was deleting a partition on my root drive through the disk utility, and now the disk utility shows my root disk is entirely free space.

My system is still running and I can access all my files just fine - `lsblk` shows the partitions just as they should be.

Is it even possible to delete the root partition, or is this likely just a bug with the disk utility?

Comment: What do you mean by a _"..a partition on my root drive..."_ ? Please post the output of `lsblk`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With such attempt, even if you're unable to delete `/` entirely, you could still get your system to crash! But for that you'll need root privileges.

The command,

```
sudo rm -rf /
```

or

```
sudo rm -rf /*
```

will delete every files from all the RW mounts. This will case the system to crash because of possible deletion of important system files.

So it's said that you should take extreme care while working as root.

*"...with great power comes great responsibility."*

#### Protection of the filesystem root: <sup>[source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rm_%28Unix%29#Protection_of_the_filesystem_root)</sup>

In modern contex, *Sun Microsystems* uses `rm -rf /` protection so that executing the command reports removal of `/` is not allowed. The same functionality was introduced into *FreeBSD* version of `rm` utility. GNU `rm` refuses to execute `rm -rf /` if the `--preserve-root` option is given, which now is the default behaviour for the command.